# How to put an Armature in a Book

Tags: rigging

I have a very basic book I made, just two covers, the pages are all attached to the covers, and  a basic 3 part armature. I tried weight painting it so the left cover was fully painted on the left bone, the spine is only the rear, and the right was fully painted on the right bone. Went through every face, but it doesn't have the desired effect. 
Here's some screenshots for reference,
[image: Book]
[image: Book 2]
I thought I removed all weight from the spine for both of the bones, but it still has a very weird effect. I'm very new to rigging, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I don't know how to fix it haha.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you should better parent With Empty Groups then assign vertices to groups in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, and Assign button

Comment: So, basically instead of weight painting, assign one bone to one half of the book's vertices? How do you go about doing this?

Comment: as I said, parent With Empty Groups (instead of With Automatic Weight), which means the mesh will have vertex groups but no vertices affected to these groups for the moment, select the vertices you want to assign to a bone, then go in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, choose the group the vertices are supposed to be part of, and click the Assign button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of non-organic object, don't parent *With Automatic Weight*, parent *With Empty Groups*, it will avoid some bones to influence some vertices they are not supposed to influence. *With Empty Groups* creates as many vertex groups as bones you have, with the same names, but there are no vertices affected to these groups for the moment.

Once parented, select the vertices you want to assign to a bone, go in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Vertex Groups*, choose the group the vertices are supposed to be part of (the group that has the name of the bone that is supposed to control that group), and click the *Assign* button.

You can affect vertices to different bones, and decrease the influence of the group on some vertices with the *Weight* value under the *Assign* button. It may be necessary to make the object more flexible.

[image]

Comment: Oh okay, I was able to get it somewhat working, I think I need to add some more loop cuts haha, thanks!

Comment: not sure my armature is correct though, it was just made for demonstration   ;)